# Table toggle not working in Safari... works fine in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table, safari

I have a simple table that also has a td that is offset and acts as a toggle. It switches between 3 states and is working fine in Chrome. Can anyone help me and explain why it does not currently work in Safari, I have not tested this in other browsers yet, but would like solution to work in other browsers too.

Pic and code attached.

Thank you for any help and solutions.

M.

[image: Comparison of Chrome and Safari]

```css
highlight {
    background-color: #86C440;
    color: white;
}

th {
  font-size: 30px;
}

tr {
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #d4d6d3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

tr {
  position:relative;
  transform:scale(1,1);
}

td.last{
  position:fixed;
  border: 5px solid #d4d6d3;
  background-color: #4eafef;
  left: -46px;
  top: -46px;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  line-height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <html>
        
    <body>
<div id="switch">1</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<style>

  table          {border-collapse: collapse; border: 5px solid white; padding: 5px;}
  table td       {text-align: center; color: black; border: 5px solid white; padding: 10px; height: 66px; width: 66px;}
  
</style>


<table class="center">
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td id="toggle" class="last" onclick="toggle1()"></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>

    <script>

    function toggle1() {

                var key = document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML;

              if (key == 1) {

                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderStyle = "solid";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderColor = "#d4d6d3";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderWidth = "5px";
                      document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = 2;

                            //console.log("toggle clicked 1st time!");

              } else if (key == 2) {

                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundColor = "#a370f0";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderStyle = "solid";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderColor = "#d4d6d3";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderWidth = "5px";
                      document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = 3;

                            //console.log("toggle clicked 2nd time!");

              } else if (key == 3) {

                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundColor = "#4eafef";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderStyle = "solid";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderColor = "#d4d6d3";
                      document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderWidth = "5px";
                      document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = 1;

                            //console.log("toggle clicked 3rd time!");

              }

    }

    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" in Safari, is it doing anything at all? Could you describe what happens (e.g. are any of the console.logs happening?).

Comment: I dont think this is the cause of your problem but just to note that you have several ids of ROW2. This is not legal HTML, ids must be unique. Consider changing them to class.

Comment: The fixed in Safari seems to be working more correctly than in Chrome - the toggle td is there but off screen with the negative left and top settings. Is there a reason for using a td for this? It makes the table a little odd with 3 cells in one row and 2 in the others. Could you just separate it out into a separate element and thus avoid the need for fixed?

Comment: Have replaced the html so no clashing ids. Have added a 2nd image showing what is happening in safari. (the toggle disappears and the white borders are not showing). As A Haworth pointed out maybe the toggle is off screen!. Still not sure how to fix. Will try to separate toggle but on the actual table there are additional cells above the numbered cells that span them.

Comment: The toggle is there on Safari, only off screen. To me Safari is doing the correct thing, fixing the toggle relative to the viewport.

Comment: Is the toggle to be fixed relative to the top of the table or relative to the viewport?

Comment: Yes fixed to the table. But what is Not shown in this simple version is that there are some cells above the numbers than span across them that contains a message. The height of which would be different to the toggle (in the same row) so that was why I was trying the offset transform approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems which seem to result in Chrome/Edge behaving differently from Safari.

There is a style declaration within the body rather than the head element. This is picked up by an HTML validator as illegal HTML. The snippet below moves it to the head.

There is a setting for tr elements which implements a transform. This seems to encourage Chrome to position the fixed element relative to the table start rather than relative to the viewport. I don't have a full explanation for this other than to note that any sort of transform seems to result in this behaviour and that any transform will create a new stacking context.

There is a 3rd cell in the first row but not in the subsequent rows. This is picked up as a warning by the validator. I do not know how the table's layout is supposed to look in this circumstance, but of course the result is complicated by the fixed setting which takes the 3rd cell out of the flow visually.

This snippet takes the 3rd cell out and puts a button before the table instead. Together with the other changes Safari and Chrome/Edge now behave the same, with Safari doing the expected behavior on border-collapse.

The button's position needs working on - perhaps the button plus table should be in a container which gets positioned? It depends on exactly what is required in terms of fixing its position.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    highlight {
      background-color: #86C440;
      color: white;
    }
    
    th {
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    tr {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    td {
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color: #d4d6d3;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .center {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    /* REMOVED
tr {
  position:relative;
  transform:scale(1, 1);
}
*/
    
    #toggle {
      position: fixed;
      border: 5px solid #d4d6d3;
      background-color: #4eafef;
      /* REMOVED
  left: -46px;
  top: -46px;
  */
      /* values changed */
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      rline-height: 7px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- MOVED FROM body -->
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 5px solid white;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    table td {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      border: 5px solid white;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 66px;
      width: 66px;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>



  <div id="switch">1</div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="toggle" class="last" onclick="toggle1()"></button>

    <table class="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <!-- td last removed -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


  <script>
    function toggle1() {

      var key = document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML;

      if (key == 1) {

        document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderColor = "#d4d6d3";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderWidth = "5px";
        document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = 2;

        //console.log("toggle clicked 1st time!");

      } else if (key == 2) {

        document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundColor = "#a370f0";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderColor = "#d4d6d3";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderWidth = "5px";
        document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = 3;

        //console.log("toggle clicked 2nd time!");

      } else if (key == 3) {

        document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundColor = "#4eafef";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderColor = "#d4d6d3";
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.borderWidth = "5px";
        document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = 1;

        //console.log("toggle clicked 3rd time!");

      }

    }
  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and answer, I also really appreciate you taking the time to help me understand what the code was actually doing. Will continue to tweak the code to get the toggle closer again to the table. But you have helped me greatly . Thanks.